# Asymptotic expansion question

Tags: integration, asymptotics, gamma-function

How may I use Watson's Lemma to find the full asymptotic expansion for;

$$ I(\lambda)= \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda(1+s)}ln(1+s^2)ds $$

as $\lambda \rightarrow \infty$.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What part of Watson's lemma are you having trouble with? The general steps are (1) Expand $\ln(1+s^2)$ in power series about the point $s=0$ and (2) substitute this power series into the integral and integrate term-by-term.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function
$$f(t) = \int_0^\infty e^{-s} \ln(1 +t^2s^2) ds,$$
We have $f(0) =0, f'(0)=0$ and 
$$f''(0) = 2\int_0^\infty e^{-s} s ds =2$$
hence $f(t) = t^2 + o(t^2)$ when $t\to 0$

By changing variable, 
$$I(\lambda) = e^{-\lambda} \lambda^{-1} f(\lambda^{-1}) = \frac1{e^\lambda \lambda^3} + o\left(\frac1{e^\lambda \lambda^3}\right).$$

Comment: may you elaborate on your working out please?

I cant really follow this, sorry for the inconvenience.